# When using amsmath, can the spacing between the letters "l " and "n" resulting from calling \ln be widened?

Tags: latex-base

The ln resulting from using \ln is too tightly spaced.

Comment: Why do you think so? This isn't random, `\ln` is defined (essentially as `\operatorname{ln}` ) by the folks behind AMSmath...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. Anyway, here's a comparison: at each stage I add `0.1mu` of space between the letters.

When you have found the value that satisfies you, do

```latex
\let\ln\relax % undefine \ln
\DeclareMathOperator{\ln}{l\mspace{<the value>mu}n}
```

in your document preamble.

[image]

By the way, one more reason to use “log” instead of the dreaded symbol “ln”.

Comment: Many thanks - regarding the comment that it is standard letter spacing is irrelevant.  As a key maths operator, such close spacing makes it weak.

Comment: @keith77777 To the contrary, it makes more evident it's a single symbol, at least IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

It is the standard letter spacing defined by the roman font in use.

original (from `latex.ltx`)

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\ln{\mathop{\operator@font ln}\nolimits}
```

However if you really must you could use

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\ln{\mathop{\operator@font l\mkern 1mu n}\nolimits}
\makeatother
```

or whatever space you want to add

Comment: Never heard about `\DeclareMathOperator`? And `\hspace` wouldn't scale in subscripts and superscripts.

Comment: @egreg ask the person who wrote `latex.ltx` from which I copied the original definition, then showed how to change it.....

Comment: @egreg I was going to use an mkern but didn't want to add extra complication, perhaps I ought to.

Comment: Don't you need some `\makeatletter` for `\operator@font`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat such definitions ought to be in package code so that's implicit but I'll add one since you asked...